# Using Git on development + release servers

Tags: git, version-control

Our company has been using Git for several months now for our 3 developers and they're all happy with how the system works, but we still manually FTP files for our webapp.

We're keen to put a true version control system in place but we currently use multiple servers in our development and deployment routine.

*2 parallel free areas of development that are uncontrolled and see concepts come together.*

1. Alpha Server A
2. Alpha Server B

*When concepts are at a 80% production state, they can be examined in a controlled area.*

1. Beta Server

*Once features has been approved in terms of functionality, they are built into a release branch in Git and deployment begins.*

1. Staging Server

*When full testing on the staged changes has taken place, the commercial directive is given to deploy the release.*

1. Release Server

There are 5 separate apache environments, would it be appropriate to set each one of these up as a remote repo which can then be pushed to?

We currently use a hosted Repo at Bitbucket as a central repo, how would this fit in/would we still need it?

Any comments on how this can be optimised?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no need to have multiple remote repos you could just manage with multiple branches instead.

At my work we run two main branches develop and master and four server environments: localdev, integration, staging and production.

We build new features by creating a branch off master locally. To get it on integration we merge it into develop and push to origin - this then pulls automatically on integration via a hook on github. To get it to staging we merge into master and push to origin again this auto updates the server... once we are happy with the state of master we tag and deploy the tagged version to production manually... it works fairly well... what we are doing is pretty much [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) but with a few extra merges to other environments for a bit more testing.

So its definitely possible to get away without having multiple repos... and probably a little easier!